# Can I link overlay for war-file in ear file?

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10, jboss-modules

I use ovelray in wildfly like this:

```
    <deployment-overlays>
        <deployment-overlay name="dep-lib">
            <!-- ... -->
            <content path="/WEB-INF/lib/org-springframework-spring-aop-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar" content="77d0b86238df32cb15e469eaa2f7f32c4893dc54"/>
            <content path="/WEB-INF/lib/org-springframework-spring-aspects-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar" content="d5327b3d4a74f224d32c338e83789ae877feb790"/>
            <!-- ... -->
            <deployment name="root.ear/core.war"/>
        </deployment-overlay>
    </deployment-overlays>
```

Now I create ear archive like this:

```
    root.ear
    |
    |-META-INF
    |        |-application.xml
    |
    |-core.war
    |-some.war
```

and I want link my overlay for core.war in root.ear.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case shwould be work:

```
<deployment-overlays>
    <deployment-overlay name="dep-lib">
        <!-- ... -->
        <content path="/WEB-INF/lib/org-springframework-spring-aop-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar" content="77d0b86238df32cb15e469eaa2f7f32c4893dc54"/>
        <content path="/WEB-INF/lib/org-springframework-spring-aspects-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar" content="d5327b3d4a74f224d32c338e83789ae877feb790"/>
        <!-- ... -->
        <deployment name="core.war"/>
    </deployment-overlay>
</deployment-overlays>
```